# converting object to dynamic nested form array and edit in html

Tags: angular, contenteditable, formarray, formgroups

```
 DData = {
    pData: [
      {
        unit: "a",
        date: "2020-10-25",
        qty: 0
      },
      {
        unit: "b",
        date: "2020-10-25",
        qty: 0
      }
    ], sData: [
      {
        unit: "c",
        name: "C",
        date: "2020-10-25",
        qty: 4138
      }, {
        unit: "K",
        name: "g",
        date: "2020-10-25",
        qty: 6498
      }
      , {
        unit: "i",
        name: "p",
        date: "2020-10-25",
        qty: 117
      }, {
        unit: "K",
        name: "M",
        date: "2020-10-25",
        qty: 0
      }
    ]
  }
```

above is my object I just created a formgroup for corresponding object using below code

```
dDataForm:FormGroup;
const groupP = this.DData.pData.map(p => {
      return new FormGroup({
        unit: new FormControl(p.unit, Validators.required) ,
        date: new FormControl(p.date, Validators.required),
        qty: new FormControl(p.qty,Validators.required)
      })
    })
const groupS = this.DData.sData.map(s => {
      return new FormGroup({
        unit: new FormControl(s.unit, Validators.required),
        name: new FormControl(s.name, Validators.required),
        date: new FormControl(s.date, Validators.required),
        qty: new FormControl(s.qty,Validators.required)
      })
    })

    this.dDataForm = new FormGroup({
      pData: new FormArray(groupP),
      sData: new FormArray(groupS)
    })
```

I just converted my object (DData) into form group (dDataForm) using the above code, but its not possible for me to display this form group in my html. my html code is not working. Though I want to create a editable data table.

I am asking for the first time I tried many wase nothing worked. Any help.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
<form [formGroup]='dDataForm'>
    <table>
        <tbody formArrayName='pData'>
            <tr *ngFor="let pro of dDataForm.controls.pData.controls; let ploop = index;">
                <div formGroupName='ploop'>
                    <td> <input type="text" formControlName='unit' [placeholder] = 'ploop.unit'> </td>
                    <td> <input type="text" formControlName='date' [placeholder] = 'ploop.date'> </td>
                    <td> <input type="text" formControlName='qty' [placeholder] = 'ploop.qty'> </td>
                </div>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <table>
        <tbody formArrayName='sData'>
            <tr *ngFor="let sro of sData.controls; let sloop = index;">
                <div formGroupName='sloop'>
                <td> <input type="text" formControlName='unit' [placeholder] = 'sloop.unit'> </td>
                <td> <input type="text" formControlName='name' [placeholder] = 'sloop.name'> </td>
                <td> <input type="text" formControlName='date' [placeholder] = 'sloop.date'> </td>
                <td> <input type="text" formControlName='qty' [placeholder] = 'sloop.qty'> </td>
                </div>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

I just go through the angular formarray documents https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray

You should loop over FormArray. You should use "controls" to get the form group from form array.